# "Tried connecting on an already connected socket" - Socket.IO-Client-Swift

Tags: ios, sockets, socket.io, swift4

I am using swift 4 and Socket.IO-Client-Swift, '~>13.1.1' (latest version). 
I tried to call socket.connect() after adding socket handlers but I was getting an error "Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open". So I have added socket.connect() code inside a timer and calling it after 5 seconds, so engine was already opened by that time and not getting that error anymore.

But now I am getting the error "Tried connecting on an already connected socket", even though connect client event handler was never called.

I have gone through the documentation and all the issues that were posted on git but no explanation on how to solve this or why this error even occurs.

You can find the code and console log below.

```
 let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "https://socket.******.**")!, config: [.log(true),.connectParams(["token":Utils.getToken()]),.reconnects(true)])
 socket = manager.socket(forNamespace: "/**********")


console log:
   2018-02-01 02:20:00.810496+0530 *******[2476:1630437] LOG SocketIOClient{/**********}: Adding handler for event: connect
   2018-02-01 02:20:00.837403+0530 *******[2476:1630437] LOG SocketIOClient{/**********}: Adding handler for event: message
   2018-02-01 02:20:00.838168+0530 *******[2476:1630437] LOG SocketManager: Manager is being released
   2018-02-01 02:20:05.815458+0530 *******[2476:1630437] LOG SocketIOClient{/**********}: Tried connecting on an already connected socket
```

From the console log, you can see that I am getting "Manager is being released" error msg. Is there a way to retain the manager object? Is that the main reason behind this issue?

Comment: Info at this link (http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/inetprog/unix-socket-faq-4.html#ss4.2) may help.

Comment: **Manager is being released** LOG SocketManager: Manager is being released. The manager needs to be a propery or global. It's getting released by ARC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sockets created through the manager are retained by the manager. So at the very least, a single strong reference to the manager must be maintained to keep sockets alive. (As per docs, https://nuclearace.github.io/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Classes/SocketManager.html)

Easiest way to fix this is create singleton class to retain the manager object

```
    open class SocketConnection {

        open static let `default` = SocketConnection()
        private let manager: SocketManager
        private var socket: SocketIOClient

        private init() {
             manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "https://socket.******.**")!, config: [.log(true),.connectParams(["token":Utils.getToken()]),.reconnects(true)])
             socket = manager.socket(forNamespace: "/**********")
        }
    }
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I have checked the documentation, But I thought it is not necessary to use a singleton class. It should have been mentioned clearly that it is..

Comment: Please make sure you have correct path and ports are open.

Comment: it's working for first time after when am emit a data it's says "Tried emitting candidate when not connected"